# Removing unwanted characters and editing Column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, multiple-columns, rename

I have pandas df with certain column names. The column names are as below,

> u'Kanta/City', u'Aluepaso/Regional Level', u'Akue/District', u'Seotukartakudi/Map code', u'k�/Age', u'2015', u'2016', u'2017', u'2018'.

What I would like to do is, rename the columns in one line of code as below,

> 'City', 'Regional_Level', 'District', 'Map_Code', 'Age', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'.

Is there any efficient way of doing so (with lambda function)?

Comment: @ Kripalu Sar [what you should do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  must learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using lambda:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('/')[1].replace(' ','_') if '/' in x else x, inplace= True)

df.columns
> Index(['City', 'Regional_Level', 'District', 'Map_code', 'Age', '2015', '2016',
           '2017', '2018'],
          dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest will be with using `replace` using regex.

```
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Kanta/City, Aluepaso/Regional Level, Akue/District, Seotukartakudi/Map code, k�/Age, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
Index: []

>>> df.columns.str.replace('.*[\\\/]', '')
Index(['City', 'Regional Level', 'District', 'Map code', 'Age', '2015', '2016',
       '2017', '2018'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Regex explanation:**

> `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below `[\\\/]`
>
> `\\` matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive)
>
> `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: I don't understand the minus voting without any comment or reflection of suggestion?